# Create New Folder - 1 Of the Save Buttons Does Nothing

Tags: folder

I'm running into a strange issue when a user tries to create a new Folder in a Doc. Library the pop up has 2 save buttons. The top save button works, but the bottom does nothing. I'm at a bit of a loss. I tried recreating the upload.aspx, but to no avail. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image: 2Saves Buttons]

Answer (score 0):

I'ts a hack, but I ended up adding the following to my custom CSS.

[id$="_toolBarTbl"]{

```
display:none
```

}

I'm not proud of it, but it works.